# Mobile Programming for Blackberry, iPod, and Android

Tags: mobile

I bought an iPod touch 3rd Gen half year ago, and I got recently an iPad WiFi. I also have a Onyx Bold Blackberry.
I don't have a Mac Book or any other apple product of laptop.

As a programmer, I speak C, Delphi and Java.  I'd like to start playing around in mobile application.

I don't know whether I should start in Blackberry platform, iPod /iPad platform, or Android platform.

Ok, for each platform, what is the cheapest way to get started to play around the language?
1. Blackberry
2. iPod
3. Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of least resistance and also of lowest cost for you is Java development for Android. Only problem, you don't seem to have an Android phone. Though i'm sure you can pick up a used one cheap.

Why: The Eclipse IDE is free, there are free Eclipse plugins available from Google for Android dev, there's no annual dev cost like with iPhone/iPad development

Answer (score 2):

Learn HTML5 and you can build apps that can work on all platforms such as IPhone/IPad, Android and Blackberry. You can just build a mobile version of your site such as mobile.mysite.com. You can then choose to implement the server side with the language of your choice/familiarity.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should start with an Android phone. You will be able to write your applications in Java, and test your applications on the device. The iPhone requires that you write your applications in objective-c, and requires developers to be a part of the iPhone Developer's Program in order to run their applications on an actual device (The membership fee is $99/year).

The documentation for the Android OS is superb, and once you have installed the Android SDK with the Eclipse Plugin, you can have a hello world application finished in a few minutes.

Comment: The market for iPod/iPhone is better for now than for Android. But in the next two - three years, I believe Android will have serious contribution in the market.

Comment: It might be inconvenient that you need to buy an Android device. However, if you were to begin iPhone development, you would need to buy a Mac and a subscription to the iPhone Developer's Program. Despite the fact that you already own Apple hardware, it is still possible that it is cheaper to begin developing for the Android. (Provided you do not pay for a new two year contract from a service provider.)

I am ignorant of the development environment of the blackberry. Perhaps that is the best option for you.